# Wildfly Stops right after it is started

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, jboss, wildfly

I have followed this [link](https://gist.github.com/sukharevd/6087988) to install Wildfly on EC2 Linux instance. After it was installed I tried to run the server using

```
service wildfly start
```

After a while it threw an error.

[image]

It says wildfly server started with errors but the server was not started infact stopped right after it was started. This is my Log file.

```
2016-07-20 09:18:10,571 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.1.Final
2016-07-20 09:18:11,255 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
2016-07-20 09:18:11,499 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) starting
2016-07-20 09:18:11,502 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] (MSC service thread 1-2) Configured system properties:
    [Standalone] = 
    awt.toolkit = sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
    file.encoding = UTF-8
    file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
    file.separator = /
    java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
    java.awt.headless = true
    java.awt.printerjob = sun.print.PSPrinterJob
    java.class.path = /opt/wildfly/jboss-modules.jar
    java.class.version = 52.0
    java.endorsed.dirs = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-0.b14.10.amzn1.x86_64/jre/lib/endorsed
    java.ext.dirs = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-0.b14.10.amzn1.x86_64/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext
    java.home = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-0.b14.10.amzn1.x86_64/jre
    java.io.tmpdir = /tmp
    java.library.path = /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
    java.net.preferIPv4Stack = true
    java.runtime.name = OpenJDK Runtime Environment
    java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_91-b14
    java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
    java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.specification.version = 1.8
    java.util.logging.manager = org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
    java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vendor.url = http://java.oracle.com/
    java.vendor.url.bug = http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
    java.version = 1.8.0_91
    java.vm.info = mixed mode
    java.vm.name = OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
    java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
    java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.specification.version = 1.8
    java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.version = 25.91-b14
    javax.management.builder.initial = org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder
    javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory = __redirected.__DatatypeFactory
    javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory = __redirected.__DocumentBuilderFactory
    javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory = __redirected.__SAXParserFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory = __redirected.__XMLEventFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory = __redirected.__XMLInputFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory = __redirected.__XMLOutputFactory
    javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory = __redirected.__TransformerFactory
    javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory:http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema = __redirected.__SchemaFactory
    javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom = __redirected.__XPathFactory
    jboss.home.dir = /opt/wildfly
    jboss.host.name = ip-172-31-25-47
    jboss.modules.dir = /opt/wildfly/modules
    jboss.modules.system.pkgs = org.jboss.byteman
    jboss.node.name = ip-172-31-25-47
    jboss.qualified.host.name = ip-172-31-25-47
    jboss.server.base.dir = /opt/wildfly/standalone
    jboss.server.config.dir = /opt/wildfly/standalone/configuration
    jboss.server.data.dir = /opt/wildfly/standalone/data
    jboss.server.deploy.dir = /opt/wildfly/standalone/data/content
    jboss.server.log.dir = /opt/wildfly/standalone/log
    jboss.server.name = ip-172-31-25-47
    jboss.server.persist.config = true
    jboss.server.temp.dir = /opt/wildfly/standalone/tmp
    line.separator = 

    logging.configuration = file:/opt/wildfly/standalone/configuration/logging.properties
    module.path = /opt/wildfly/modules
    org.jboss.boot.log.file = /opt/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log
    org.jboss.resolver.warning = true
    org.xml.sax.driver = __redirected.__XMLReaderFactory
    os.arch = amd64
    os.name = Linux
    os.version = 4.4.11-23.53.amzn1.x86_64
    path.separator = :
    sun.arch.data.model = 64
    sun.boot.class.path = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-0.b14.10.amzn1.x86_64/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-0.b14.10.amzn1.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-0.b14.10.amzn1.x86_64/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-0.b14.10.amzn1.x86_64/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-0.b14.10.amzn1.x86_64/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-0.b14.10.amzn1.x86_64/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-0.b14.10.amzn1.x86_64/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-0.b14.10.amzn1.x86_64/jre/classes
    sun.boot.library.path = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-0.b14.10.amzn1.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64
    sun.cpu.endian = little
    sun.cpu.isalist = 
    sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
    sun.java.command = /opt/wildfly/jboss-modules.jar -mp /opt/wildfly/modules org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/opt/wildfly -Djboss.server.base.dir=/opt/wildfly/standalone
    sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
    sun.jnu.encoding = UTF-8
    sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
    sun.os.patch.level = unknown
    user.country = US
    user.dir = /opt/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/bin
    user.home = /root
    user.language = en
    user.name = root
    user.timezone = Etc/UTC
2016-07-20 09:18:11,502 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] (MSC service thread 1-2) VM Arguments: -D[Standalone] -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/opt/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/opt/wildfly/standalone/configuration/logging.properties 
2016-07-20 09:18:16,598 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
2016-07-20 09:18:16,664 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-2) XNIO version 3.3.4.Final
2016-07-20 09:18:16,708 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-2) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.4.Final
2016-07-20 09:18:16,919 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.18.Final
2016-07-20 09:18:17,066 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
2016-07-20 09:18:16,992 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
2016-07-20 09:18:17,085 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
2016-07-20 09:18:17,104 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
2016-07-20 09:18:16,975 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
2016-07-20 09:18:17,087 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
2016-07-20 09:18:17,363 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 2 core threads with 16 task threads based on your 1 available processors
2016-07-20 09:18:17,433 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.3.15.Final starting
2016-07-20 09:18:17,849 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.3.15.Final starting
2016-07-20 09:18:17,861 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.4.Final
2016-07-20 09:18:17,850 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.3.2.Final)
2016-07-20 09:18:18,081 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
2016-07-20 09:18:18,162 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
2016-07-20 09:18:18,173 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
2016-07-20 09:18:18,708 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
2016-07-20 09:18:19,244 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path '/opt/wildfly/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
2016-07-20 09:18:19,731 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 4 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
2016-07-20 09:18:19,733 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
2016-07-20 09:18:19,943 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
2016-07-20 09:18:20,327 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 0.0.0.0:28080
2016-07-20 09:18:20,328 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
2016-07-20 09:18:21,779 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.3.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.4) 
2016-07-20 09:18:22,045 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Mahou' 8.1.0.Final
2016-07-20 09:18:22,208 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /opt/wildfly/standalone/deployments
2016-07-20 09:18:22,208 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
2016-07-20 09:18:23,028 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
2016-07-20 09:18:23,028 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
2016-07-20 09:18:23,029 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) started in 13530ms - Started 267 of 553 services (371 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
2016-07-20 09:20:40,572 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-2) WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been requested.
2016-07-20 09:20:40,617 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
2016-07-20 09:20:40,762 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0019: Host default-host stopping
2016-07-20 09:20:40,780 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTP listener default suspending
2016-07-20 09:20:40,781 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTP listener default stopped, was bound to 0.0.0.0:28080
2016-07-20 09:20:40,781 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = h2
2016-07-20 09:20:40,785 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0004: Undertow 1.3.15.Final stopping
2016-07-20 09:20:40,815 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0050: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) stopped in 206ms
```

Looking at this log file I am unable to comprehend the issue which causing the server to stop.

**Update-1:**

Thanks to @James R. Perkins I looked at /var/log/wildfly/console.log and the issue is wildfly was unable to write to its child files. Like

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log (Permission denied)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYDR0006: Directory /opt/wildfly/standalone/data/content is not writable
```

Even though wildfly is owner of wildfly parent folder

[image]

Do I have to make it the owner of all of its sub folders?

Comment: I think the `wildfly started with errors, please see server log for details` means the Linux server logs not the WidlFly server logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to my particular problem was the issue of permissions. Only root had permissions but all the children didn't had wildfly as owner. Applying

```
chown -R
```

did the job. Thanks to **@James R. Perkins** I checked my console logs that were in **/var/logs/wildfly/console.log** i found the issue.